# jQuery adding unwanted characters to string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm using a jQuery to add localised currency signs to a page. Seemingly an innocent and straightforward procedure:

```
$('.currency').text( userCurrency() )
```

However, if the currency string is `£`, instead the output is `Â£`.

I've got no idea what might be causing it, as I cannot recreate the issue in jsFiddle.

It doesn't happen in firefox, ie or safari, only chrome.

By setting a breakpoint at the function call it is possible to see that the text is not actually visible (or loaded?) in the browser (even though the code is only run after the window has loaded).

I understand I'm not giving you much to work with, and I'm sorry - this is a very bizarre issue indeed.

Has anyone out there encountered anything similar, maybe someone has ideas how I can go about troubleshooting?

Comment: jsfiddle probably has utf-8 encoding in its headers

Comment: How are you encoding the data? (UTF-8 would be recommended)

Comment: @Anonymous `<meta charset="utf-8"> ` is present in my `<head>`. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: is the js file utf-8 encoded or wherever the characters are coming from?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm not sure, I've never had to do it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Some editors (like textpad) have the option to change the encoding when saving, if the file that the character list is coming from is not utf-8 encoded as well it might be why you are getting that.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks, that's all it took! Write it as an answer and I'll mark you as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the different encodings used. Make sure all documents use the utf-8 encoding, along with setting the meta tag for utf-8. But also as in Qambar Raza's answer mentions you should probably use the html entity of certain characters instead of the actual character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this in your  of the HTML page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

It basically sets the content type of your page to ('utf-8') encoding meaning it can support the character set for currency.

Also, make sure you use HTML entities like:

```
&pound; for £
```

i.e your function userCurrency() should return html entities (e.g £)  rather than a direct symbol. You can find more details about this topic on the following link:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-cur.htm